# How to avoid httpd restart/reload (mod_wsgi) on adding/deleting a tenant

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, multi-tenant

In our multi-tenant architecture (apache, django, mysql)

For each new tenant we create, we add a conf file(/etc/httpd/conf.d/)  e.g., customer1_http.conf

We tried mod_wsgi, touch wsgi(mod_wsgi), but Apache able to pick the newly added tenant (unless we reload)

- WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
- WSGIDaemonProcess customer1.com processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
- WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/org/site/dc/customer1_wsgi.wsgi

Is there any better alternative (other than restart/reload) to make Apache know about the newly added/removed conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a single Apache, consider using separate instances for each WSGI application by using mod_wsgi-express (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi). Then have Apache or nginx as a front end load balancer. This will give you better control over each instance and restarting the front end to add/remove sites will not cause the WSGI applications to be restarted.

A further option is to use Docker to run each instance as that could simplify the setup and management of each site.

For a discussion about proxying using Apache to multiple instances of mod_wsgi-express (with Docker, but still relevant if not using Docker), see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html

Depending on how many sites and machines you need to manage, as well as what other sort of infrastructure you need to run, down the track you may want to look at systems such as Kubernetes and OpenShift to help you manage this sort of stuff.